# Slim request header is setting text/html, even i am using withJson.

Tags: php, slim

I am using slim withJson method to return header application json. But its returning text/html header. When i echo header of response object, it is application/json. So why it is returning text/html header in rest client or browser.

```
$app->get('/login', function($request,$response){
$data = [['name'=>'vaibhav']];
$newResponse = $response->withJson($data);
echo $newResponse->getHeaderLine('Content-Type');
return $newResponse;
});
```

Comment: Which slim version? for me this works all well with version 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are doing `echo $newResponse->getHeaderLine('Content-Type');`and then slim tries to send headers.
Try to comment echo string and check.

Comment: I used it to check the header. Without echo also header text/html is coming.

Comment: Very strange. I just tried to use your code in new Slim-Skeleton app and it works correctly. Response returned with header: Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8

Maybe the problem isn't here.