# Slim's withJson doesn't properly set Response Content-Type header

Tags: php, json, slim, content-type

I am trying to send a JSON with :

```
return $response->withJson ($full_config, 200) ;
```

Problem : it doesn't set the `Content-Type` to `applciation/json` :

- It sends and response with `Content-Type` to `text/html; charset=UTF-8`
- The **body** contains :

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/json

  here_be_my_wanted_json_content
  ```

NB1 : This post seems to be a duplicate of [Slim request header is setting text/html, even i am using withJson.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139245/7031981), but it's been 2 years without answers, and I'm trying to add more information.

NB2 : This doesn't fix anything :

```
return $response
    ->withJson ($full_config, 200)
    ->withHeader ('Content-Type', 'application/json') ;
```

NB3 : This fixes the problem :

```
return json_encode ($full_config) ;
```

But :

- This is annoying since I can't add statuses or additional headers.
- This isn't very "the Slim way to do it".

NB4 : I am using Slim version 3.12.1

NB5 : I am retrieving the response in a javascript (jQuery) with

```
$.get(url, function (data, status) {
    if (status === 'success')
        console.log (data)
});
```

Comment: Can you check and see if there are any extra characters printed before json output? I mean, fill `$full_config` with very simple data, an empty array for example, and see if the output has any extra characters.

Comment: Oh ! Yes. Actually : I just tried to send an empty array, what I have : 

- In the header : still 'Content-Type' : 'text/html'

- And the body is : `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

[]` It's like if ... headers have been put in the body ? ... I don't understand. :/

Comment: Can you try to create a new, minimal app, with only one route to test this? For example do `composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton sample-app` and add a single route and in the handler `return $response->withJsone([])`. This helps to make sure you're not sending anything other than your desired response.

Comment: ->withJson works perfectly if I try to implement a minimalist project how you asked. (I have 'Content-Type' : 'applciation/json')

Comment: How does `return json_encode...` fix the problem?! Can you include more code please? The problem seems to be rooted in other parts of your code.

Comment: if I replace `return $response->withJson ($full_config, 200) ;` with `return json_encode ($full_config) ;` Slim will actually send a Response with a decent `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'`.
Problem is that my project is 34k lines of code, with several password and classified information hidding here and there. Maybe I could try to extract a "minimal working code", but it'll take a lot of time.

Comment: A minimal example would help a lot.

Comment: The withJson method in Slim 3 does set the correct Content-Type to application/json, see [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L359). Do you use any middleware?

Comment: @Nima I am working on making a minimal example, it will take a while though.

Comment: @odan Yes I do use a middleware, but I can't find anything related to content-type. Do you have "guesses" about stuff that could lead to this kind of behavior ?

Comment: @Motiss Try disabling all middleware handlers, and then check if the problem is fixed.

Comment: @odan Ok. I just did : nothing changed, same behaviors.